# Mongo functions updating wrong record

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

My issue is that when I attempt to use some API routes that I have created to Update, Delete, or Get any individual records from my MongoDB it seems to ignore the id being passed to it and perform the action on the first record in the list. Here is a sample of records in my database:

```
[
    {
        "_id": "614271f38e5401f65dc86ee1",
        "name": "Test2",
        "title": "Test2"
    },
    {
        "_id": "614271fb8e5401f65dc86ee2",
        "name": "Test3",
        "title": "Test3"
    },
    {
        "_id": "614272018e5401f65dc86ee3",
        "name": "Test4",
        "title": "Test4"
    }
]
```

So for example if, using Postman, I send a DELETE request to http://localhost:5000/api/614272018e5401f65dc86ee3 it would delete Test2, then Test3, and finally Test4. I don't understand why it is ignoring the id parameter. Here are the routes I have created:

```
const express = require("express");

// recordRoutes is an instance of the express router.
// We use it to define our routes.
// The router will be added as a middleware and will take control of requests starting with path /record.
const routes = express.Router();

//This will help us connect to the database
const dbo = require("../../config/db");

routes.get('/test', (req, res) => res.send('tech route testing!'));

// Get
routes.route("/techs").get(function (req, res) {
  let db_connect = dbo.getDb("employees");
  db_connect
    .collection("techs")
    .find({})
    .toArray(function (err, result) {
      if (err) throw err;
      res.json(result);
    });
});

routes.route("/techs/:id").get((req, res) => {
  let db_connect = dbo.getDb("employees");
  var myquery = { id: req.body.id };
  db_connect
    .collection("techs")
    .findOne(myquery, function (err, result) {
      if (err) throw err;
      res.json(result);
    });
});

// Create
routes.route("/techs").post(function (req, res) {
  let db_connect = dbo.getDb("employees");
  let myobj = {
    name: req.body.name,
    title: req.body.title
  };
  db_connect.collection("techs").insertOne(myobj, function (err, res) {
    if (err) throw err;
  });
});

// Update
routes.route("/update/:id").put(function (req, res) {
  let db_connect = dbo.getDb("employees");
  let myquery = { id: req.body.id };
  let newvalues = {
    $set: {
      name: req.body.name,
      title: req.body.title
    },
  };
  db_connect
    .collection("techs")
    .updateOne(myquery, newvalues, function (err, res) {
      if (err) throw err;
      console.log("1 document updated");
    });
});

// Delete
routes.route("/:id").delete((req, res) => {
  let db_connect = dbo.getDb("employees");
  var myquery = { id: req.body.id };
  db_connect.collection("techs").deleteOne(myquery, function (err, obj) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log("1 document deleted");
  });
});

module.exports = routes;
```

Answer (score 0):

Not `req.body.id` but `req.params.id` in your `delete` function.